# (Clickable) cross-reference in lstlisting

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, listings

To generate documentation for an 'application programming interface', I would like to have a syntax highlighted area (with the class declaration), which has clickable links to the documentation (which is specific per method).

The reason for the clickable links is twofold:

- To allow quick jumping to the method documentation.
- To prevent having to synchronize the class declaration and the method declaration elsewhere in the document.

Tried so far:

1. `lstlisting` in combination with `escapeinside` option. The link works; however , the link text is *not* syntax-highlighted.
2. [`minted`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted), which has a `mathescape` option, but no `escapeinside`. If supported, I doubt if it would highlight the link text.

Does anyone have an idea?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

% #1: label name
% #2: function declaration
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\func}[2]
{
    % Label for full declaration
    \edef\@currentlabel{#2}
    \phantomsection
    \label{#1}
    % Text printed where \func{...} is used
    #2
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% Method info
\func{fn:getage}{int GetAge()} \\
More info...

% Class declaration
\begin{lstlisting}[language=c++,keywordstyle=\color{blue},escapeinside='']
class Employee
{
    % Would like to insert (clickable) link here, like
    % \ref{fn:getage}
    int GetAge();
}
\end{lstlisting}

% Reference to method (full declaration)
\ref{fn:getage}

\end{document}
```

**Attempt with `escapeinside` (only `lstlisting`)**

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=c++,keywordstyle=\color{blue},escapeinside='']
class Employee
{
    % Clickable link works, but no highlighting/formatting
    '\ref{fn:getage}'
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common problem, and is related to the way [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) processes its input. When you escape within a listing, no listing-related processing occurs, so you'll find that not only the formatting changes, but also the natural spacing. Moreover, you'll notice a difference between the spacing supplied via `lstlisting` and the inline `lstinline`. Either way, the following is a way to achieve what you want, albeit rather cumbersome:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

% #1: label name
% #2: function declaration
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\func}[2]
{%
    % Label for full declaration
    \edef\@currentlabel{#2}%
    \phantomsection
    \label{#1}%
    % Text printed where \func{...} is used
    #2%
}
\makeatother

\newsavebox{\lstsavebox}

\begin{document}

% Method info
\func{fn:getage}{int GetAge()}

% Store listings link in box
\begin{lrbox}{\lstsavebox}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=c++,keywordstyle=\color{blue}]
int GetAge();
\end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}

% Class declaration
\begin{lstlisting}[language=c++,keywordstyle=\color{blue},escapeinside='']
class Employee
{
    % Would like to insert (clickable) link here, like
    '\hyperref[fn:getage]{\strut\smash{\usebox{\lstsavebox}}}'
    int GetAge();
}
\end{lstlisting}

% Reference to method (full declaration)
\ref{fn:getage}

\end{document}
```

In principle we capture the text-to-be-hyperlinked in a box *outside* the `lstlisting` where it should be used. We use the same formatting (which you can set globally, of course). Then, inside the listing, use the boxed content - via `\usebox` - to set a `\hyperref[<link>]{<stuff>}`.

Since the box may include other vertical adjustments (as a result of it being in a "display listing"), we `\smash` it, together with a `\strut` to retain some regular vertical spacing.